# Scala Seq delete row

Tags: scala

I am trying to execute the below code.

> val input = 0

```
scala> val list = Seq((1,2,3),(4,5,6),if(input == 1)(15,16,17),(7,8,9),if(input == 1)(10,11,12))
```

After executing above code I am getting below result.

> list: Seq[Any] = List((1,2,3), (4,5,6), (), (7,8,9), ())

But I need below output -

> List((1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9))

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1, wrap all in `Option`s and call `flatten`:

```
val list = Seq(Option((1,2,3)),Option((4,5,6)), 
  if(input == 1) Option((15,16,17)) else None,
  Option((7,8,9)), 
  if(input == 1) Option((10,11,12)) else None).flatten
```

Option 2, if the ordering doesn't matter, you could flatten only the optional ones:

```
val must = Seq((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9))
val maybe = Seq(if(input == 1) Option((15,16,17)) else None,
  if(input == 1) Option((10,11,12)) else None).flatten

val list = must ++ maybe
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array already and want to filter the empty array after the result

```
list: Seq[Any] = List((1,2,3), (4,5,6), (), (7,8,9), ())
```

you can do simply `list.filter(_ != ())` which gives output as

```
List((1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9))
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Your `if(input == 1)(10,11,12)` does not have any `else`.

You can try it yourself and do:

val input = 0
val x = if(input == 1)(10,11,12)

You'll see `x` will be `Any`. (not `Unit` as previously stated)

It's not clear though what you're tying to do.

Comment: `x` is of type `Any`, not `Unit`. A `else ()` statement is implicitly added, so it takes the least upper bound of types `Tuple3[Int, Int, Int]` and `Unit`, which is `Any`.